# Flexslider next and previous buttons are not clearly visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

All functionalities are working properly. However, the previous and next buttons are not clearly visible when hovered over it.

What `CSS` elements should we change to make the icons more visible?

Here's an screenshot:

[image]

Here's my js code:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide"
    });
```

and the iteration using laravel:

```
<div class="flexslider flex">
            <ul class="slides">
              @foreach($ads as $ad)
              <li><img src="/storage/avatars/{{$ad->image}}" alt="image"></li>                              
              @endforeach                            
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: Show us your code, what have you tried and what did not work

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please, add the relevant code that you are using to achieve this result. Take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The most important part is to [create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you deployed your code on any server?

Comment: Hi guys! Thanks for your feedback. I added a code snippet please do check it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your index is to low:

```
   .classOfYourButtons{z-index: 9999; color: yellow; }
```

pls post your Code to analyze your problem

Comment: I added code snippet please take time to review. Thanks.

Comment: I did not add js code for the buttons since I've used the library.

Comment: Thanks to your feedback guys. This issue has been fixed now.